# How to create html helper in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

The code I'm currently using is this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaxExecutions)
<div class="input-append">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MaxExecutions, new { @class = "input-xxlarge", placeholder="Enter Max Executions" })
    <span class="add-on"><a href='#' class='title' rel='tooltip' title="Help Title" data-content="Help Message">?</a></span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaxExecutions)
</div>
```

I repeat this over & over in my code. I'd love to pass this off to an HtmlHelper. The type of Model I pass in can change, and I'd like to have the Display attribute available from the model (or I'd just generate an htmlstring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement an extension method or a helper (static) class but there's times where I like the declarative version (CSHTML). Either way works and can be passed around from controller, etc.

~/App_Code/Blah.cshtml

```
@helper ExecuteHelper() {
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaxExecutions)
   <div class="input-append">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MaxExecutions, new { @class = "input-xxlarge",    placeholder="Enter Max Executions" })
    <span class="add-on"><a href='#' class='title' rel='tooltip' title="Help Title" data-content="Help Message">?</a></span>
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaxExecutions)
   </div>
}
```

Then call it in view like:

```
@Blah.ExecuteHelper()
```

I've noticed the amount of HTML you have it in which is why I opted for the @helper syntax solution. Here's an article by Scott Guthrie that outlines this MVC feature: 
[Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)

Comment: Definitely didn't know you could arbitrarily define & execute code like that. Certainly a new tool to add to my belt. I'm still not sure how I'd "genericize" this to use any model type & associated property, though... any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for the late response but you can try adding the model as a parameter that will be used inside the helper. It would be @Blah.ExecuteHelper(model)